# How to join two jquery methods into one statement?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using jquery to display bootstrap modal and want to add custom message at runtime. Here is what I am doing? but wondering if there is a way to merge two lines into one:-

```
$("#modalBody").append("saved successfully");
$("#modal").modal("show");
```

Bootstrap Modal:-

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
            </div>
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
                *adding custom message*
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it can be combined to one line, however, it would likely be faster to keep it as is. (i also consider it easier to read in this form rather than using .closest to make it one line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$("#modal").find("#modalBody").append("saved successfully").end().modal("show");
```

It's probably simple enough without combining them though.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the newline character.

```
$("#modalBody").append("saved successfully"); $("#modal").modal("show");
```

Script engine will use the semicolon to determine where one statement ends and the next begins.

I hardly see the point, though.